# When do I need to #include .cpp files?

Tags: c++, include, header-files

One of my homeworks involves three files: LineType.h, LineType.cpp, and Driver.cpp. Driver.cpp contains the main() method which uses a class defined by LineType.h and LineType.cpp.

On my system, Driver.cpp starts with:

```
#include "LineType.h"
#include "LineType.cpp"
#include <iostream>
```

And the program compiles and runs perfectly when I run `g++ Driver.cpp` from within the project directory via the command line. However, when my instructor attempts to compile the program (I believe she uses Eclipse), it fails to compile. After some back-and-forth, she was able to fix the problem on her end by commenting out one of the #includes from Driver.cpp:

```
#include "LineType.h"
//#include "LineType.cpp"
#include <iostream>
```

When I attempt to run `g++ Driver.cpp` on this edited file, my compiler complains about "Undefined symbols for architecture", which I understand to mean that it cannot find definitions for the class/methods being called.

What are my instructor and I doing differently to cause this difference in behavior? Why does a line required by my compiler cause her compiler to fail?

Comment: Beginners should *never* need to include source files. Instead you should read up on *separate compilation* and *object files* and *linking*.

Comment: You should never `#include` a cpp file. Your instructor's build system does something more like `g++ Driver.cpp LineType.cpp` (although it's better than that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `#include somefilename` means that content of *somefilename* is put in place of the include.
By putting `#include "LineType.cpp"` in your Driver.cpp file you efectively put everythig in one file and then compiling using `g++ Driver.cpp` works fine for you.
When your instructor used IDE for compiling it went on separate compile and linking. So it compiled Driver.cpp and LineType.cpp Both files contain definitions from LineType.cpp due to that include. So when it came to linking, she had everything definded in LineType.cpp twice and linker didn't know what to do.
You can compile and link multiple files at once by using

```
g++ Driver.cpp LineType.cpp
```

Or using separate compile and linking commands

```
g++ -c Driver.cpp
g++ -c LineType.cpp
```

Which will generate files `Driver.o` and `LineType.o`. Then you can combine them together by running

```
g++ Driver.o LineType.o
```

Answer (score 9):

You should *never* include source files directly.

Instead, you should list all your source files in the `g++` command when you compile:

```
g++ Driver.cpp LineType.cpp MyOtherFile.cpp # etc...
```

Comment: For the lazy beginner, use `g++ *.cpp` and you'll get every cpp file in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I strongly do not recommend to `include` source files. 
But author of this [article](https://accu.org/index.php/journals/2360) claims that including source files can reduce large project compilation time in orders. He calls this ‘unity builds’ and claims the approach is widely used in games industry. The main idea of unity build is to reduce the number of modules in a compilation. Like this:

```
my_unity_build_1.cpp:

#include "renderer.cpp"
#include "ui_elements.cpp"
#include "gameplay_code.cpp"
#include "character_AI.cpp"

my_unity_build_2.cpp:

#include "file_io.cpp"
#include "cat_dynamics.cpp"
#include "wobbly_bits.cpp"
#include "death_ray.cpp"
```

Fewer modules mean less duplication common functions and less code generation. [Modules](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4667.pdf) allow to reduce compilation time dramatically but still are not in standard.

Comment: There is a certain amount of (umm) religion among game programmers (like any other group).  There is often some truth behind the religion, but also over-acceptance of dogma.  For example, preferring complete rebuilds over incremental builds or complex headers (e.g. with template instantiation) included in multiple compilation units increase total (not incremental) build times. It is sometimes claimed that unity builds help compiler optimisers, but that argument is weakened by modern toolchains that support link time optimisation.

Comment: @Peter, there is something beyond a religion. A merge of multiple source files into a single one means that the common header files would be included only once. I came here exactly to clarify this vision of mine, and it seems like I'm not much mistaken. However care must be taken, as the article points out, since although the global aim might be benign and the source files might have much in common, they can differ in little details, which might prove to be fateful.

So my verdict is: good idea, but dangerous and requires great caution. And more also, I'm waiting for modules very much