# Linker says a function is already defined if I try to define it in another file (running tests)

Tags: c++, testing, linker

I have the following files in a testing project:

Test.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "PrintOne.cpp"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace PointandVectorCreationTest
{
    TEST_CLASS(PointandVectorCreationTest)
    {
    public:
        
        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            std::string expected = "1\n";

            std::stringstream buffer;
            std::streambuf* sbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); // Save cout's buffer
            std::cout.rdbuf(buffer.rdbuf()); // Redirect cout to the stringstream buffer

            int result = printOne();

            // When finished, redirect cout to the original buffer 
            std::cout.rdbuf(sbuf);
            std::cout << "std original buffer: \n";
            std::cout << buffer.get();

            // Test
            Assert::AreEqual(expected, buffer.str());
        }
    };
}
```

PrintOne.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int printOne() {
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to run this test in Visual Studio, the linker throws the following error:

> Error LNK2005 "int __cdecl printOne(void)" (?printOne@@YAHXZ) already defined in PrintOne.obj

This error is thrown when linking `Test.obj`.

I'm not defining `printOne` anywhere in `Test.cpp`. In fact, if I just copy the definition of the function to `Test.cpp` and eliminate the `PrintOne.cpp` file like so:

Test.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <iostream>

int printOne() {
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace PointandVectorCreationTest
{
    TEST_CLASS(PointandVectorCreationTest)
    {
    public:
        
        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            std::string expected = "1\n";

            std::stringstream buffer;
            std::streambuf* sbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); // Save cout's buffer
            std::cout.rdbuf(buffer.rdbuf()); // Redirect cout to the stringstream buffer

            int result = printOne();

            // When finished, redirect cout to the original buffer 
            std::cout.rdbuf(sbuf);
            std::cout << "std original buffer: \n";
            std::cout << buffer.get();

            // Test
            Assert::AreEqual(expected, buffer.str());
        }
    };
}
```

The test runs just fine. I'd rather avoid writing all the functions I use in the same file I test them, so to me this shouldn't be a solution.

Why does the linker throw this exception? How can I fix this so I can keep my function definitions separate from the testing file?

Comment: `#include "Test.cpp"` includes itself recursively.

Comment: That's old and I changed some file names for calirty, my bad. I'm editing the equestion, the problem persists

Comment: Please be sure to copy-paste your code exactly as it is in your editor. Don't edit after pasting.

Comment: Just did, I actually cloned it and copied the original instead of the clone - my bad

Comment: Never include .cpp, it breaks usual behaviour of build systems. You may rename PrintOne.cpp to PrintOne.h and declare printOne inline.

Comment: That works, thank you. If you don't mind, why should I declare it as inline?

Comment: Inline functions do not produce multiple definitions.

Comment: So the compiler just copypastes the code into each call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not defining `printOne` anywhere in `Test.cpp`.

Actually, you are, when you `#include` the source code of `PrintOne.cpp` into `Test.cpp`.  If you then compile and link both `Test.cpp` and `PrintOne.cpp` together, the linker indeed sees 2 definitions of `printOne()`, one in each `.obj` file.

For what you are attempting to do, you need to add a `.h` file that just **declares** `printOne()`, and then you can `#include` that file into both `.cpp` files, where only one of them **defines** `printOne()`, eg:

Test.cpp:

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "PrintOne.h"

using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace PointandVectorCreationTest
{
    TEST_CLASS(PointandVectorCreationTest)
    {
    public:
        
        TEST_METHOD(TestMethod1)
        {
            std::string expected = "1\n";

            std::stringstream buffer;
            std::streambuf* sbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(); // Save cout's buffer
            std::cout.rdbuf(buffer.rdbuf()); // Redirect cout to the stringstream buffer

            int result = printOne();

            // When finished, redirect cout to the original buffer 
            std::cout.rdbuf(sbuf);
            std::cout << "std original buffer: \n";
            std::cout << buffer.get();

            // Test
            Assert::AreEqual(expected, buffer.str());
        }
    };
}
```

PrintOne.h

```cpp
#pragma once
int printOne();
```

PrintOne.cpp:

```cpp
#include "PrintOne.h"
#include <iostream>

int printOne() {
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a line like `#include "PrintOne.cpp"` in your `Test.cpp` file, then the entire contents of `PrintOne.cpp` (including the definition of the `printOne()` function) will be included in `Test.cpp`'s source code; thus, the `Test.obj` file will contain a definition of the `printOne()` function.

If you then also have the `PrintOne.cpp` file included in your project - as it seems from the fact that the linker is referencing a `PrintOne.obj` module - then there will *also* be a definition of the `printOne()` function in that object file, too.

So, you have multiple (though identical) definitions of the function, as signalled by the linker.

To avoid this, replace the inclusion of the `PrintOne.cpp` *source* file with one for a header (say `#include "PrintOne.h"`) that provides a **declaration** (prototype/signature) for the `printOne` function (The contents of the source file will be added, anyway, if it is part of the project.)

Generally, it is not advisable to `#include ...` source (cpp) files (though there are *some* circumstances where it can be useful). Worth reading: [When do I need to #include .cpp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45110783/10871073)

Comment: "*To avoid this, simply remove the `#include "PrintOne.cpp"` line*" - it is not enough to just remove it. You have to *replace* it with something that defines the `printOne()` function, so that `Test.cpp` can still *call* the function.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, indeed. Edited.